# Is there a way to make an integrated circuit at home (without using expensive parts?)

Tags: integrated-circuit

I've seen lots of people like Jerri Ellesworth build integrated circuits at home from silicon wafers, but she used a massive furnace to do it, and not all of us have a huge 2000 degree furnace at our homes.

I want to build my own integrated circuit; building a transistor or logic gate from a disc of silicon is one of my dreams. Is there any way to build an integrated circuit at home without purchasing thousands of dollars of material?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/how-are-integrated-circuits-fabricated

Comment: This might be of interest: http://sam.zeloof.xyz/category/semiconductor/

Comment: Yes. Bell Labs, in the 1960's, developed a kit (and instructions) where you would make your own silicon solar cell, at home. It wasn't even a particularly expensive kit. See [here](https://beatriceco.com/bti/porticus/bell/belllabs_kits_se.html) for photos and some details. Separately, I was able to make a fab at home from a nickel-plated, water-cooled, lamp-heated quartz chamber. However... I only used it with dry nitrogen back-fill for experimenting with temperature control of wafers. Fabs use dangerous gases like silane, phosphine, and arsine. Once could buy them at home but likely not now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are integrated circuits fabricated?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/how-are-integrated-circuits-fabricated)

Comment: @jonk Are you saying that a photovoltaic cell is an integrated circuit, as the term "integrated circuit" is commonly defined? I don't think this is a reasonable equivalent.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have built a small home RTP using a water-cooled, nickel-plated (couldn't afford gold), quartz chamber. I've also spent worked as a FAB consultant with Applied Materials and their suppliers. I think the Bell Labs kit was a wonderful introduction and it does require you to produce rather high and similar temperatures in an oven you build (they provide details.) Consider some of the very earliest IC products from the early 60's. You're certainly entitled to an independent opinion about what's "reasonable." Obviously, I can't debate your internal state of mind.

Comment: @jonk I really just asked a simple question, trying to illuminate **your** internal state of mind. Are you saying that a photovoltaic cell is an integrated circuit, as the term "integrated circuit" is commonly defined? It's a simple yes or no question. Since the OP wants to build an integrated circuit, I think it is a reasonable thing to ask.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It sounds as though you want to set up a strawman ('commonly defined' is a part of it) that would set the tone of a discussion and perhaps prepares an all too easy conclusion. I'm not interested in walking through your prepared door. Is this really a serious question? If so, email would be the route. Not here.

Comment: @jonk I think the OP deserves some clarification of how fabricating a solar cell might compare to fabricating an integrated circuit. I think that information needs to be here along with the associated comments. This is a very serious question. In my opinion, your comment, starting with the simple sentence "Yes." will mislead the OP and other readers.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My intent was to be more a matter of encouragement. A long path always starts with that first step. Let's leave it there.